# Can not download nuget packages

Tags: nuget

I'm getting the following error:

`WARNING: The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme.`

This started happening randomly. I'm not behind a proxy, and restarting did not fix anything.

Comment: Can your network firewall Cut http requests?

Comment: If by cut you mean make, then yes. I am to browse the web quite fine.

Comment: Damned t9 ,i mean maybe the firewall blocks https requests. ..we had a similar problem (can't remember the exact error) but sometimes it was bloocking request sometimes no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the following in my machine.config file:

```
<system.net>
<defaultProxy
                enabled = "true"
                useDefaultCredentials = "true">
<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

This was causing the issue. Must have been leftover from a fiddler crash.

Comment: thanks man, was the same for me here, hard to guess!